# word vba search for <tn>, If <tn> is active more than 3 times in a paragraph change all to <FRED> i.e. FRED<tn>Wilma<tn>Pebbles<tn>BamBam<tn>Dino

Tags: vba

I need to search and replace `<tn>` with `<NEST>`, but only those that appear more than twice in each paragraph/line:
i.e. 
Flintstones`<tn>`Fred`<tn>`Wilma (leave this paragraph as is)

Flintstones`<tn>`Fred`<tn>`Wilma`<tn>`Pebbles`<tn>`BamBam`<tn>`Dino (change to)
Flintstones`<NEST>`Fred`<NEST>`Wilma`<NEST>`Pebbles`<NEST>`BamBam`<NEST>`Dino

I have tried, but my knowledge is very limited.
Thanks in Advance for Help you may give.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small macro which will do the work for you. Happy VBA :-)

```
Public Sub ReplaceTN()
**Dim J As Integer
For J = 1 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count**
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Select
    If UBound(Split(Selection.Text, "<tn>")) > 2 Then
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "<tn>"
            .Replacement.Text = "<NEST>"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End If
**Next J** End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, this seems to replace all occurrences of <tn>, not just the third and fourth etc in any one line. Sorry if I am sending confusing signals, first timer you see.

Comment: Code Updated to replace <tn> from each para instead of whole doc. Find the change marked between **. Hope this is what you are looking for.